# Как получить this.props в конструкторе?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как я могу применить `this.props` внутри конструктора?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
import React from 'react';

import Electron from '../Electron'

class Arbital extends React.Component {


 constructor() {
  super();
  this.arbitalWidth = document.querySelectorAll('.animate-electron__arbital')[this.props.arbitalNum];
 }


 render() {

  
  return(
   <div className="animate-electron__arbital">
    <Electron arbitalNum={this.props.arbitalNum} />
   </div>
  )
 }
}

export default Arbital;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного упрости все но думаю все будет понятно:

```js
class Arbital extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {width:0}
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const div = this.myRef.current
    this.setState({width:div.getBoundingClientRect().width}) 
  }

  render() {
    const {width} =  this.state
    return (
      <div ref={this.myRef} className="animateelectron__arbital">{width}</div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Arbital />, document.querySelector('main'))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Comment: Как я могу значение из  componentDidMount() передать в props следующему компоненту?

Comment: вложенному или родительскому?

Comment: Вложенному, за пределом этой функции переменная не видна.

Comment: Обновил ответ.. там через state  в рендер пробрасываем.. и можно потом значение это уже в пропс бросить

Answer (score 2):

1. ```
   class Arbital extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
   ```
2. Нечего из конструктора по DOM'у лазить.

Comment: А как тогда по правильному DOM элемент достать нужный?

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, вероятно, в cmoponentDidMount?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html - достать элемент. но вопрос, зачем?

Comment: @СергейПетрашко, мне нужно получить html ноду, а вернее ссылку на нее, чтобы узнать ширину этого элемента

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, и это вполне можно сделать в didMount.

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, кстати вопрос. А это тот же элемент, который ты рендеришь или другой?

Comment: @СергейПетрашко, я полагал, что он другой элемент ищет.

Comment: @Qwertiy , ну судя по селектору - тот что оборачивает Electron

Comment: @Qwertiy, а да, это тот же элемент, а я голову ломаю, почему undefined)))

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, значит используй ref как в соседнем ответе написали.